# Save all PHP error_reporting's notices into a file

Tags: php

I would like to save all error_reporting's notices into a file so that it can be read easily.

I'm using CLI to run my PHP script. The notices are outputs all at once, and as you already know, the console's scroll-bar position just can be moved to the topmost place for me to read notices there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe the console output to a file using the redirection operator >.  For example, when I run my php scripts on the console, I type

```
% php < test.php
```

To redirect the console output to a file, I could type

```
% php < test.php > out.txt
```

The console output then goes to out.txt instead of the screen.

Comment: Just to add that if you're on windows and the messages are going to the standard error stream, you may need to use > out.txt 2> err.txt to redirect error messages

Comment: You don't need to pipe a file into the `php` executable, `$ php test.php` works just fine.

Comment: :-D Thank you, I know that, I just would like to know who is generous to me. I accept your reply to increase your reputation.

Comment: @deceze - :) thanks for pointing that out.  Funny how you discover one way of doing something and it becomes an ingrained habit...